# How do I overwrite the variables in my theme?

Tags: 7, theming

```
function rate_preprocess_test(&$variables) {
  extract($variables);
  $buttons = array();
  foreach ($links as $link) {
    $button = theme('rate', $link['text'], $link['href']);
    $button .= $link['votes'];
    $buttons[] = $button;
  }
  $variables['buttons'] = $buttons;
}
```

I want to overwrite the `$link['votes']` variable to add a `<span>` tag around `$link['votes']`.

This is the code I added to template.php, but it doesn't contain the `<span>` tags that I  added.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_test(&$variables){
    $link['votes']='<span>'.$link['votes'].'</span>';
}
```

I want to add the `span` tags around `$link['votes']`.

Comment: May you provide the complete code of the `foreach()` statement you reported in the first block? What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? If you mean that the button doesn't contain the `<span>` tags you add, then I could know why that happens.

Comment: Thank you. The answer I gave then applies, if the first function is defined inside a module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wondering why the `<span>` tags don't appear in the button output from `rate_preprocess_test()`, that is probably because `mytheme_preprocess_test()` is called after `rate_preprocess_test()`.
I take `rate_preprocess_test()` is defined inside a module; in that case the preprocess function defined inside the module is invoked before the implementation of the preprocess function contained in the theme, as reported in the documentation for [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/6), which lists the preprocess functions in the following order:

- template_preprocess(&$variables)
- template_preprocess_HOOK(&$variables)
- MODULE_preprocess(&$variables)
- ENGINE_engine_preprocess(&$variables)
- ENGINE_engine_preprocess_HOOK(&$variables)
- ENGINE_preprocess(&$variables)
- ENGINE_preprocess_HOOK(&$variables)
- THEME_preprocess(&$variables)
- THEME_preprocess_HOOK(&$variables)

Comment: To notice that the parameter list for the preprocess functions reported in the documentation for `theme()` is not correct. For example, the parameters for `template_preprocess(&$variables)` are really `template_preprocess(&$variables, $hook)`; the same is true for every preprocess function that doesn't contain `_HOOK` in its name.